# whats the problem with the custom power function I designed(javascript)?

Tags: javascript, function, pow

The question which is suggested it is a question which is based on calculating fractional power of number but I wanted it simply in integer form.The function power is showing the powers correctly of a number raised to power b but it is not stopping as expected it should be.When I try to return the sum as return sum at the end of function power it is just loading and showing nothing please help me.Any help will be greatly appreciated.I cant use the built in pow() function.Thanks.

```js
function power(a, b) {
  a = parseInt(a);
  b = parseInt(b);
  var sum = 1;
  var result;
  var pow = 1;
  for (var i = 1; i <= b; i++) {
    pow = 1;

    if (i == 1) {
      pow = a * i;
      sum = 1;
    } else {
      i--;
      pow = a * i;
      sum = sum * pow;
      alert(sum);
    }

  }

}
var a = prompt("Enter the number a for calculating its power?");
var b = prompt("Enter the number for calculating pow of a i.e enter power of a");

var answer = power(a, b);
alert("a^b is equal to : " + answer);
```

Comment: Why are you re-inventing the wheel? [`Math.pow()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow)

Comment: @Liam Probably an assignment

Comment: Lol, what a pointless thing to do :) I love how lazy academics just come up with this stuff that'll you'll never do in real life. Just do `power(a,b){ return Math.pow(a,b);}` A*

Comment: @ Alon Eitan I have been assigned this work and I have to do this in my custom function without the built in function Its my javascript course one of assignments

Comment: @Liam Man I have to do it myself without the built in function

Comment: Just saying https://stackoverflow.com/a/23987676/542251

Comment: Your actual issue seems to be you never `return pow` BTW. Though I'm also not sure your function actually calculates pow either

Comment: At the start of the loop `i` equals to 0, then you decrement it by one, on the next round `i` is 0 again, and you decrement it by one etc. What is the purpose of `i--`?

Comment: @Liam Its a very difficult algorithm I want it in a simple way

Comment: You do `i++` and `--i` at each loop. The value of  `i` is always 0, resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: @Teemu I decremented it because the power function didnt calculated the power correctly and it was calculating wrong now in alerts it is giving correct powers of number a raised to power b but bot loading just again and again incrementing if I return its not stopping just loading

Comment: You should not touch `i` inside the loop that way, it always remains at zero, and the loop will never finish. You've to fix the logic to work without changing `i` inside the loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing your own exponential power function with decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982504/writing-your-own-exponential-power-function-with-decimals)

Comment: @Sir I have got an answer but the suggested one involves fractions.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in recursive function call, check this out.,

```js
var power = function(a, b) 
{

a = parseInt(a);
b = parseInt(b);


   if (b === 0) 
   {
    return 1;
    }
  else 
  {
    return a * power(a, b-1);
  }
};

var a = prompt("Enter the number a for calculating its power?");
var b = prompt("Enter the number for calculating pow of a i.e enter power of a");



alert("the result "+  a + " ^ " + b + " is "  + power(a, b));
```

Comment: Or even as a one-liner : `const power = (a,n) => n===0 ? 1 : a * power(a, n-1);`